# How to collapse javascript functions with <%= in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 when editing markup/aspx, you can apparently collapse javascript functions as long as they don't contain special server tags such as the shortcut for Response.Write **<%=**.

**Examples:**

Can collapse:

```
function foo() {
    var x = 0;
}
```

Can **not** collapse:

```
function bar() {
    var x = $find("<%= txtWhatever.ClientID %>");
}
```

I've noticed as soon as you add the opening tag **<%=**, the collapse option (**-**) to the left of the word **function** disappears, so I know that's the problem.

It appears to break the collapsing of the entire function regardless of size/contents.

I've tried the [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) plugin as well as the [Advanced Javascript outlining](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4be701d8-af03-40a4-8cdc-d2add5cde46c) plugin, but neither seems to work for functions with this particular content either.

Is there any way to make functions containing these types of tags collapsible?

Thanks-

Comment: Not sure about a direct fix, but a workaround would be to just wrap it in its own script tags.

Comment: Well, that might not be too bad if I didn't have several functions.  :(   Not a bad idea though.

Comment: Actually, it works with multiple functions, see http://jsfiddle.net/T87XJ/
It may not be your exact scenario, but same idea I think.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant it'd be a little bit of a pain (and extra markup) for the extra script tags.  You're right though, it would prob work fine.

Comment: Ok, I thought that is what you might of meant, and yes I agree.

Comment: FYI, I talked to Mads Kristensen on twitter about this.  He opened a bug with the JS team for me. I dont think there's much we can do right now because of the way VS works.  :(

Comment: I see, well at least he opened a bug on it, so maybe in the near future :)

Comment: if you'll post your workaround comment as an answer, i'll mark it so you'll get credit.  i think that's about the only solution possible right now.

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft has not fixed this even in Visual Studio 2017. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Only a workaround:**

Wrap each function in its own script tag.

A bug has apparently been opened with the JS team about this.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "Three Script" pattern:

## ***Script 1***

---

Page level variables.

## ***Script 2***

---

'Getter/Setter' functions that return references to server controls or get/set values.

For example:

```
function GetTxtUserNameVal() {
    var rtn = $('#<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>').val();
    return rtn;
}

function SetTxtUserNameVal(arg) {
    $('#<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>').val(arg);
}

function GetUserDetailsGrid() {
    return $find('<%= gridUserDetails.ClientID %>');
}
```

## ***Script 3***

---

Functions:

In these, I use the getter/setter functions above instead of server tags.

---

Now I can collapse the scripts and also can collapse individually all the functions in the Functions script.